# Cannot set a property dynamically in an object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined

My goal is to set properties like name, hidden and no_parent dynamically but it keeps giving me:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Even if I initialized `scorcroot` before passing it by parameter.

Here is the code:

```
adattamento: function(data) {
    var continua = true;
    var scorcfat = this.famiglia;
    var scorcroot = {};
    this.controlloprimi(scorcroot, scorcfat);
    this.root = scorcroot;
    console.log("hey!")
    console.log(this.root);
  },
  controlloprimi: function(scorcroot, scorcfat) {
    scorcroot.name = scorcfat.name;
    scorcroot.hidden = false;
    scorcroot.no_parent = true;

    if (scorcfat.father != null) {
      if (scorcfat.mother != null) {
        scorcroot.children = [{}, {}, {}];
        this.controlloprimi(scorcroot.children[1], scorcfat.father);
        scorcroot.children[2].name = "";
        scorcroot.children[2].hidden = true;
        scorcroot.children[2].no_parent = false;
        this.controlloprimi(scorcroot.children[3], scorcfat.mother)
      } else {
        scorcroot.children = [{}]
        this.controlloprimi(scorcroot.children[1], scorcfat.father);
      }
    }

    if (scorcfat.mother != null) {
      scorcroot.children = [{}, {}];
      this.controlloprimi(scorcroot.children[1], scorcfat.mother);
    }
  },
```

Comment: Make sure `scorcroot.children[2]` is not `undefined`. Just a pointer, index in JS starts from 0 and not 1

Comment: Yes the problem are the numbers...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scorcroot.children[3]` is not an object as you have initialized the `scorcroot.children` array with 3 objects only. So scorcroot.children[3] is **undefined** and you are setting property on undefined.

Comment: Hi @ImFireblade please let me know if this works for you or not and accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be this line

```
this.controlloprimi(scorcroot.children[3],scorcfat.mother)
```

since you have only given 3 items in this array initialization

```
scorcroot.children=[{},{},{}];
```

it means `scorcroot.children[3]` is `undefined`

Not sure about the purpose of this code, so I would simply suggest making it 4 items instead of 3

```
scorcroot.children=[{},{},{},{}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the wrong enumeration of the arrays..
So i created an array of 3 objects and by calling array[3] i was calling the 4th undefined object